# How to interchange a column and row in a table (Transpose) in iWork Numbers?

Tags: mac, iwork, iwork-numbers

I want to transpose a table (interchange rows to columns and vice versa). How to do that in iWork Numbers.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple AppleScript that does it.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell the front document
        tell the first sheet
            set original_range to selection range of first table

            set orignal_table to first table
            set number_of_columns to column count of orignal_table
            set number_of_rows to row count of orignal_table
            set trasposed_table to make new table with properties {row count:number_of_columns, column count:number_of_rows}

            repeat with i from 1 to number_of_columns
                repeat with j from 1 to number_of_rows
                    tell orignal_table
                        set original_value to the value of cell i of row j
                    end tell
                    tell trasposed_table
                        set the value of cell j of row i to original_value
                    end tell
                end repeat
            end repeat

        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

[Here](http://wishlabs.blogspot.it/2012/10/transpose-table-with-iwork-09-numbers.html) you can find more details about it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning this formula takes the cells' `value` meaning that if you have formulas in the cells you are transposing, only their output will be transposed. The formulas will not be.

Answer (score 4):

Those using the latest version of Numbers can use the "Transpose Rows and Columns" option under the "Table" menu, as seen in [this answer over on StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15491/is-there-a-way-in-numbers-to-flip-columns-with-rows). Image below also shamelessly 'borrowed' from that answer, for easy reference.

[image]